# laravel load view from a folder name with actual dot

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am creating a multi-domain Laravel app, so my view files are in separate folders per domain. For example, the following:

```
return view('pages/' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/public/home', []);
```

should load a view under

```
pages/domain.com/public/home.blade.php
```

but instead it attempts to load

```
pages/domain/co/public/home.blade.php
```

because of the dot notation.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 5):

You'd need to add a view namespace to set up hints for a particular folder if there're dots in the name.

```
$domain = 'domain.com';

View::addNamespace($domain, config('view.paths')[0]."/{$domain}/");

Route::get('example', function() use ($domain) {
    return view("{$domain}::home");
});
```

You could use `base_path('resources/views')` instead of in the example above `config('view.paths')[0]` which is probably a bit more sensible in case someone reorders or changes the value of `config('view.paths')`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could replace the dot with underscore:

```
$domain = str_replace('.', '_', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
return view('pages/' . $domain . '/public/home');
```

and load the view under:

```
pages/domain_com/public/home.blade.php
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work

```
return view('pages/domain.com/public/home',[]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!