# Make view function in larvael escapes dots from the path

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel Application and I want to call a view using view function.
The problem is my folders may contain dots like:

```
"this.is.folder/file.blade.php"
```

Which of course laravel is going to assume it's

```
"this/is/folde/file.blade.php"
```

Which in my case the file doesn't exist!

```
$folderName = "this.is.folder";     
view($folderName.'/main/file');
```

So How can I solve this problem and make view escapes the dots in my file name!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel load view from a folder name with actual dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721328/laravel-load-view-from-a-folder-name-with-actual-dot)

Comment: Just don't use dots. They have special meaning for Laravel views. Use an underscore or hyphen or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

As stated in the comment, i've included the part of the solution - from 
 [laravel load view from a folder name with actual dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721328/laravel-load-view-from-a-folder-name-with-actual-dot)

```
$folder = 'this.is.folder';

View::addNamespace($folder, base_path('resources/views')."/{$folder}/");

Route::get('example', function() use ($folder) {
    return view("{$folder}::home");
});
```

Comment: If you see somerhing like this flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! sorry I didn't see the other link even I spend a lot of time searching.
Now is there a solution for this with **blade** when I add
`@include($folder)` it gives the same problem?

Comment: Once you defined your view namespace, you can use it for Blade. `@include('this.is.folder::viewName)`, don't forget the double colon after your namespace.

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it's a kludgy workaround that'll be **bafflingly** confusing to anyone else familiar with Laravel who winds up working on the project. The *correct* answer to this question, IMO, is "stop doing that". Laravel views shouldn't have dots in their folder names.